# Rock Vocal Production - The Strokes (Live)

Tags: voice, production, live-sound, live

I am curious about the production on the singer's voice in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8UFJb9wkXg) live performance and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-L3_dDbWLM) live performance (the effect is similar).  I'm sure you are all familiar with the vocal sounds of *Is This It* and *Room on Fire*.  The vocal sounds in these live performances seem to be different--perhaps more sawtoothy or robotic or something.  I do not have the understanding of production to know how this sound was created nor the vocabulary to fully describe what I am hearing!  I hope someone with more knowledge of vocal production techniques can help de-mystify this sound for me.

Thank you!